# Kubernetes kops change basic auth password

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I have successfully configured a Kubernetes cluster using [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops).

However, I cannot find where to change the auto-generated admin password - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no easy way to do that since there is no way via the Kops API to create a secret of type "Secret" (quite confusing I know). The only workaround is to change the credentials, in this case your password directly on your s3 configuration as explained here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/secrets.md#workaround-for-changing-secrets-with-type-secret

and force a rolling-update of your cluster by changing its configuration (I just updated to the new version of k8s for example) or simply run `kops rolling-update cluster --yes --force`

Apparently this will be addressed soon by one of the future releases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it worked!